# css table gets wrong properties

Tags: css

I have built a table which on of it's row is like so

```
<tr id="graphid+'" class="graphRow">
                <td colspan="2" style="width:5%; max-width:5%;">
                    <div class="stockData">
                        <div class="stockDatatable">
                            <table class="stocktable">
                                <tr><td id="stockDBnameid+'"></td></tr>
                                <tr><td class="Desctitle">תחום עיסוק:</td></tr>
                                <tr><td id="stockDBfieldid+'" class="stocktable"></td></tr>
                                <tr><td id="stockDBurlid+'" class="stocktable">כתובת אתר החברה</td></tr>
                                <tr><td class="Desctitle">ערך החברה:</td></tr>
                                <tr><td id="stockDBvalueid+'" class="stocktable">ערך החברה</td></tr>
                                <tr><td id="stockDBdescid+'" class="stocktable">תיאור המנייה</td></tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td colspan="8">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div id="graphDivid+'" class="GraphDiv"></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

as you can see, The row has two coloumns.
I'm talking about the second one:
it's compiled from a div->div->table->rows..
the rows get their properties from the the `class = "graphRow"` and NOT from `class ="stockTable"`.
The css is like so:

```
tr.graphRow td {background:lightgray;}
tr.stocktable td {background:blue;}
```

why is isn't working?

thanks.

Comment: I can't find a `tr` element with the class `stocktable`, but you have a table with this class.

Comment: why are you applying 'stockTable' to table and td tags??? according to your style definition you should apply it to tr tags for the inner table.

Comment: Also, be careful that you don't acidentally write "stockTable" in your source, as you did in the question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your declaration `tr.stocktable td{background:blue;}`, stocktable is applicable only for tr. But you have used stocktable for a `<table>` (`<table class="stocktable">`).

Declare stocktable like -

`.stocktable{background:blue;}`

or

`table.stocktable {background:blue;}`